# select one of arr index in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an arr.map rendered in html, how can I do it to select one of them

my arr is like
[{progress: "A" , _id: "123456"},
{progress: "A" , _id: "222363"} , ....... ]

Example:
Press the first btn to select arr[0].
Press the third btn to select arr[2].

Below is the html document

```html
arr.map((arr) => (
    <div className={arr._id} id="bookingdata" >
       <div className="booking-detail">
          <p className="booking-id" id="booking-id">
            {arr._id}
          </p>
          <p className="booking-progress">
            {arr.progress}
          </p>
          <button onClick={handledetail} className="btn">
             btn
           </button>
        </div>
      </div>));
```

Comment: What have you written in your handledetail event handler function ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
In your array of objects add one more field as isSelected and mark it as false intially 
const [data,setData]=useState(arr)

data.map((arr) => (
    <div className={arr._id} id="bookingdata" >
       <div className="booking-detail">
          <p className="booking-id" id="booking-id">
            {arr._id}
          </p>
          <p className="booking-progress">
            {arr.progress}
          </p>
          <button onClick={()=>{arr.isSelected=true}} class="btn">
             btn
           </button>
        </div>
      </div>));
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it.

If u will have a lot of items, and u want to solve it with a single handler, u can do something like this:

(in your css u will need a "selected" class)

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

function handledetail(e) {
    setSelectedId(e.currentTarget.dataset.id); // if "_id" is number Number(e.currentTarget.dataset.id)
    ...
}

data.map((item) => (
    <div className={`${item._id} ${selectedId === item._id ? "selected" : ""}`} id="bookingdata" >
        <div className="booking-detail">
            ...
            <button onClick={handledetail} data-id={item._id} className="btn">
                btn
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
));
```

Comment: arr is string. I follow your method.
Every time  press the button,  have to press it twice to select that id (the first one is the previous id)

Comment: The useState hook should take care of re-rendering (when u call `setSelectedId(n)` and `selectedId` changes your component should re-render)
**Maybe** your component is nested and u want to keep track of pervious `seletedId`, in that case u can set your initial state like `useState(prevSelectedId)`